# Access Session Variable within custom module

Tags: module, session

On my site i have several pages which set a core session variable as so:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setSellYourArtCheck(1);
```

If i want to access this anywhere i can successfully do:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getSellYourArtCheck();
```

But i now need to access this session variable in my custom module but it is showing as empty/null when i try and access it as above.

My Observer.php code for my module:

```
<?php
class Custom_RegisterArtist_Model_Observer
{
    public function registerArtist(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        // other code....

        $is_artist = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getSellYourArtCheck();
        if($is_artist == 1)
        {
            $customer->setData('group_id', 4);
        }

        // other code....
     }
}
```

My `$is_artist` variable is always empty/null within my module but is fine on any of my pages

Comment: session is not working on custom moduls?

Comment: no, its fine everywhere else (php/phtml pages etc) just not in this module

Comment: i guess that you session variable is set properly...Note that :Session variable value is not set until page refersh

Comment: The session variable is definitely set probably beforehand as before i get the module i can access it. My module is called on the customer_save_before event

Comment: hi try use customer/session...it may be help you

Comment: Tried that too without success

Comment: try to another session varibale

Comment: i guess it may be creating issue when new customer is register...

Comment: Ah ok, any ideas on a solution?

Comment: As Customer is register new session creating thus it may be created issue

Comment: rewrite customer session class Mage_Customer_Model_Session  add add new function

Comment: public function getSellYourArtCheck($value=null)
    {if(!is_null($value))$this->setData('sell_your_art_check', $value);
 }
 return $this->getData('sell_your_art_check');
    }

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your custom session variable is not set when `registerArtist()` is called. Also remember that a session is not shared among different browsers, users, and computers. Where are you setting it `1`, when are you setting it to `null`, and when does the observer `registerArtist` fired? If you don't have the order right for these, you won't have the value you're looking for, especially because in some instances, you're setting the variable to `null`.

One way to check if you're core session variables are set at all is to try `->getSellYourArtCheck(2)` instead of `->getSellYourArtCheck()`. Do you get `2` instead of `null`?